# Namespace of model(ASP MVC3) isn't visible in WorkerRole

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

I'm making my first application in Windows Azure and I have some problem.

This is list of thinks which I have done:

- add new solution
- add new MyApp.WebPage (asp.net mvc3) project
- add Windows Azure Project, and add one WorkerRole to it
- add my asp.net mvc3 project as new Web Role from solution to Windows Azure Project
- add MyClass.cs class to my WorkerRole

...and add in MyClass:

```
using MyApp.WebPage.Models;
```

so then I have this error:

```
The type of namespace name 'WebPage' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp' (are you missing an assemblu reference?)
```

I'm beginniner in Azure so I have no Idea how can I Solve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worker role is a set of code that's completely separate from your web role code, and eventually deployed to different sets of Windows Server 2008 VMs (all within the same deployment, and with the ability to communicate between vm instances over tcp or http). Your web Role contains all of your asp.net mvc code, and therefore has access to all of its libraries.

Web Role and Worker Role just define what code gets deployed alongside Windows Server 2008 VMs, with Web Roles having IIS enabled. If you put all your code in the project associated with the Web Role, all will be visible. If you need to share code between web and worker roles, you should put that code in its own dll and include it in both projects.